# How to connect to a sql database using classic asp?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

Could someone please help solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple script that you can use:

```
<%

Dim conn

Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = (local); Initial Catalog = Northwind; User Id = sa; Password="

If conn.errors.count = 0 Then

Response.Write "Connected OK"

End If

%>
```

And a def of the connection string members:

> - Provider: The provider value tells ADO which data provider it
>     should call to give us access to the
>     data that we need. "SQLOLEDB" is the
>     best provider to use for Microsoft SQL
>     Server 2000 databases. If we left out
>     the provider value, then ADO would
>     automatically default to the "MSDASQL"
>     provider, which is Microsoft’s OLEDB
>     provider for ODBC compatible data
>     repositories.
> - Data Source: The data source value
>     tells our provider the IP Address or
>     netbios name of the computer on which
>     our database is available. In our
>     example above, I have used the value
>     "(local)". This value tells the
>     provider that our database resides on
>     the local machine, and to use local
>     procedure calls instead of remote
>     procedure calls. Using this data
>     source value makes data access faster
>     because database function calls are
>     not bounced across the network and
>     back to the SQL Server like they are
>     normally.
> - Initial Catalog: The initial catalog value is just a fancy name for
>     the database that the provider should
>     connect us to by default.
> - User Id: The login Id of the SQL Server user account that the provider
>     should use during the authentication
>     process.
> - Password: The password of the SQL Server use account that the
>     provider should use during the
>     authentication process.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great simple script to use

Answer (score 1):

```
<% 'database
dbserver = ""
dbcatalog = ""
dblogin = ""
dbpassword = ""
'connection string
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=" & dbserver & ";Initial Catalog=" & dbcatalog & ";User Id=" & dblogin & ";Password=" & dbpassword
 %>
```

this is the one i use. check out http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for a bunch more

Answer (score 1):

We can connect to database using 2 approaches: OleDB or DSN

Note: You need to create system DSN as shown below

[image]

```
Session("Con") = "DSN=OL-SS;UID=test;PASSWORD=pwd"
Set objDbConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objDbConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 0
objDbConnection.Open Session("Con")
```