# How do I find the name of tables in a database? ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, database-schema

I'm working on a asp-classic vbscript website and am curious if there is a way to display the tables in a database. I have looked online and saw some examples but they don't explain what to actually do with the code. I am VERY new so if someone could make this make sense for me that would be awesome.

DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server @Ekkehard.Horner

Answer (score 2):

```
Set Cat = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
Cat.ActiveConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
For Each Table In Cat.Tables
    WScript.Echo Table.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

To get you [started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275721%28v=bts.10%29.aspx):

```
  Const adSchemaTables =         20 ' 00000014

  Dim sCS : sCS     = "...your connection string..."
  Dim oDb : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
  oDb.Open sCS
  Dim oRs : Set oRs = oDb.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
  Do Until oRs.EOF
     If oRs("TABLE_TYPE") = "TABLE" Then WScript.Echo oRs("TABLE_NAME")
     oRs.MoveNext
  Loop
```

[If you really don't know about connectionstrings, look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the response. What is meant by "my connection string" @Ekkehard.Horner

Comment: To learn more about this, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569303/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-database-using-classic-asp