# Make a connection to Sql Server using Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

I have created a form with an action attribute. I am able to take the values from the web form and display them (response.write...used for clarification that my values are being read) using my action_page. I have also created a database and a table on MS Studio Management. The step i'm stuck on is the code that is required in order to connect the web form values and the database. Thanks. 
Note: This is the action page, I did not include the form.
Note:  I am using notepad ++ and NOT visual studio.

```
<%@ Language="VBscript" %>

<%
'declare the variables that will receive the values 
 Dim name 
 Dim idnum 
 Dim product
 Dim entrydate
 Dim area
 Dim qunaity

 'receive the values sent from the form and assign them to variables
  quantity=Request.Form("quantity")
  area=Request.Form("area")
  entrydate=Request.Form("date")

  stack over
 'let's now print out the received values in the browser
  Response.Write("Name: " & name & "<br>")
  Response.Write("Quantity: " & quantity & "<br>")
  Response.Write("Area: " & area & "<br>")
  Response.Write("Date: " & entrydate & "<br>")  
  %>
```

Comment: This appears to be *Classic* ASP with VBScript which has nothing to do with VB.Net. See [MSDN: How To Create a Database Connection from an ASP Page in IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/300382/how-to-create-a-database-connection-from-an-asp-page-in-iis)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to a sql database using classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569303/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-database-using-classic-asp)

Comment: Why are you learning to code in such an outdated atmosphere? Classic ASP is long dead. There are tons of sites still running but since it seems like you are pretty new to the development world why not use a more modern language?

Comment: I am new to this. I took the project as a learning curve. Thanks for the replays. How would the above be written using the modern method. I presume your talking about asp.net??

Comment: "How would the above be written using the modern method" is far outside the scope of questions here on Stack Overflow. Drop what you've done and find an ASP.NET tutorial (preferably using modern conventions like MVC, maybe ASP.NET Core, etc.) in C#.

Comment: I must say in recent years, stack overflow is becoming more and more unhelpful. Most posts nowadays only have condescending answers from people with little to no solutions. The whole meaning of this site has being taken away from people like that

Comment: [Active Server Pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) <= refer to this. The first release was in 1996, and the latest release was in 2000. This technology over 20 years old and was last versioned 17 years ago. So you could go learning this but only do that if there is legacy software that you have to support. If that is not the case go no further. Start with a new tutorial of asp.net core. There are plenty of good tutorials out there. While you are at it find a good IDE like Visual Studio. No sense in using notepad to learn how to program.

Comment: @ThomasForan - Agreed 1000% I can't believe someone thinks a good answer would be "start over with a different language i think is better". How is that helpful? Yes, Classic ASP is old, but I would hardly say it's dead. I've been developing in it for the last 15+ years, and I will happily say I can do anything in ASP than can be done in another language. While learning ASP, I have learned the basics of client/server principles and how they work, as well as a lot of front end technologies (JS, ajax, jquery, css, etc). so yes, you can still the principles of web dev, even with an older language

Comment: Thank you for agreeing with me. It seems lately when looking through the site for possible answers, there are only links to web pages which clearly most people would have already looked at. As I am new to ASP and server side programming in general, i believe in learning any language, be it old or not is always a benefit to engineers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to a sql database using classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569303/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-database-using-classic-asp)

Comment: The above are comments, not answers. Think of comments as a discussion, a tool used to further understand the question or the intent of a question. I would also agree with you, these all would not be any good as answers. The *comments* all suggest that *if* the OP is trying to find a learning project it is not helpful to start with a dated language and framework. Realistically there is not a lot of job opportunity or future growth in that. Finding resources and help for dated languages/frameworks can also be challenging. My 2 cents.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery classic ASP has not had an update to the interpreter since IIS4. It was written in VB6. Sure it will continue to run but seriously. This is like saying, "you should learn to code in RPG, I have been doing it for a long time". I too spent quite a bit of time working in classic ASP but walked away from it for good in about 2005 or so. Just because you can do something doesn't mean it is a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasForan my guess about this site becoming less helpful is due in large part to questions that have been steadily getting worse. Nearly everything has been asked and answered already yet we continue to see new questions on the same stuff.

Comment: @SeanLange - I respectfully disagree. Just because a language is "old" doesn't mean it's still not useful. Is FORTRAN useless now? or PERL? The main reason why classic asp is still being used today is because sites built with it are still stable and working perfectly fine nowadays. It has all of the basic principles of standard client / server functionality, and since the syntax is relatively easy to learn, newbies can concentrate more on development practices. Sorry, I just don't buy into the whole "it's no longer useful because it's old" philosophy...

Comment: @JoshMontgomery I never said it is no longer useful. That is you interpreting what I wrote. What I said is if the OP is just learning to write code that it might be in their best interest to learn a more modern language. How many jobs do you really think there are using classic ASP today for somebody with little to no experience? Sure someone like you would find a job because you have a lot of experience in that language. I know I cringe when I see a site in classic ASP. Especially one that transmits sensitive data. Not because the tech can't handle but so many places has sketchy code for that

Comment: If someone asks a specific question about how to do something in Classic ASP it's because he/she has to work with it.  There could be all sorts of reasons for this, legacy sites have to be modified from time to time.  I don't think it's particulary helpful to have a discussion of the about the pros and cons of the language itself

Answer (score 1):

Again, don't listen to those who say "start over", learning classic asp as a beginner to web dev, as it's easy to learn and will get you the basics of web dev.

Check out [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/) to help finding the right connection string for you. If you have the right drivers installed (which, in this case, you should), you can probably get away with something like this:

Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;

so your code may look something like this:

```
<%@ Language="VBscript" %>

<%
'declare the variables that will receive the values 
 Dim name 
 Dim idnum 
 Dim product
 Dim entrydate
 Dim area
 Dim qunaity

 'receive the values sent from the form and assign them to variables
  quantity=Request.Form("quantity")
  area=Request.Form("area")
  entrydate=Request.Form("date")

  stack over
 'let's now print out the received values in the browser
  Response.Write("Name: " & name & "<br>")
  Response.Write("Quantity: " & quantity & "<br>")
  Response.Write("Area: " & area & "<br>")
  Response.Write("Date: " & entrydate & "<br>")  

  '-- now, connect to the database
  dim conn : set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  dim connString : connString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

  conn.Open connString
  %>
```

now you can send and retrieve data to/from the database. Any questions, feel free to ask!

Comment: Thank You very much. Much appreciated