# How do I set connection string in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, database-connection

I have copied an older classic asp project from one of the servers, I am attempting to run it locally. I have the frontend running however, to logon obviously requires an attached db, I have moved all db files and attached them to my local machine. I am now struggling to set the correct connection string for the project to run locally

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=myTCP" sqlConnectionString="data source=DESKTOP-1QG6I8F\SQLEXPRESS;user id=sa;password=" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />

<add key="mycon.ConnectionString" value="data source=localhost;initial catalog=catalog;password=password;persist security info=True;user id=sa;workstation id=localhost;packet size=4096" />
```

I believe these are the two relevant xml elements, coming from web.config

Ive never worked with Classic asp so bear with me

Ive fiddled with the code already, Changing datasource to my local pc

Any help appreciated

error code produced :An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.

The application should be logging on when entering correct login details

Comment: Are you really sure this is ASP-Classic if you have a Web.config?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to create a Data Source (DSN) in the ODBC Data Source admin snap-on. You can find this in Control Panel > Admin Tools > Data Sources. Select System DSN tab and use the Add button to create the data source. Once you have it testing correctly for your DB, you can add the connection in your classic ASP code like this:

```
Dim dbConn    
Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbConn.ConnectionString="DSN=<YOUR_DSN_NAME>;Uid=<Username>;Pwd=<Password>"
objConn.Open
```

Give that a shot and see how you do. Good luck

Comment: You [don't have to create a DSN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1569329/692942), in fact, sometimes that can be more work to manage or just not possible *(Shared Hosting)*.